# Songs of India plant dying

Tags: houseplants

[image]
My songs of India plant was brought from nursery around d two months ago. In past 3-4 days it has suddenly lost all its leaves and stem is also turning black. What do I do ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a sign of root rot caused by root diseases. Dracaena should be planted in well-drained soil to prevent soil fungus overgrow and attack the root system.

Dracaena is not afraid of clean water, [it can be propagated](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/houseplants/dracaena/dracaena-has-black-stem.htm) by cutting the healthy stem and put it into a bottle of clean water.

It is worth a try to save the plant. This can be done by cutting off the stem and inspect whether the inner stem is healthy and not showing any sign of rotting. Then put the stem into a container with clean tap water and wait for a few days.

Nevertheless, the soil of the Dracaena should either be discarded or put into compost to treat it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check: roots,watering,light insects. If the plant is a loss, you can start a new one. It's a cane plant so you can cut it and stick it in a rooting medium then dirt or, just put it in water. I have a Corn plant same thing. It's caney so I cut it and rooted it in water, now all I have to do is plant it.Check everything Pooja, good luck.!

Answer (score 0):

This Dracaena reflexa has root rot due to overwatering and low light.  It's easy to do with these plants but by the time you see the leaves dropping off the root system is done.

Try taking some cuttings as has been suggested.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracaena_reflexa) for more details where it is suggested that overwatering is very common.